# Expand dataframe but retain variables in R

Tags: r

I would like to expand a dataframe based on all pairwise combinations of one variable while keeping the associate value of a second variable. For example:

```
V1 <- letters[1:2]
V2 <- 1:2
df <- data.frame(V1, V2)
```

I would like to return:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
a    a    1    1
b    a    2    1
a    b    1    2
b    b    2    2
```

I can use `expand.grid(df$V1, df$V1)` to get all of the pairs, but I'm not sure how to include the second variable without having its values expanded also.

Comment: Try `do.call(cbind, Map(expand.grid, df, df))`

Comment: That does it exactly. Do you want to include this as an answer so I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to expand each column separately, then we can do this with `Map` where the arguments are two 'df' objects

```
do.call(cbind, Map(expand.grid, df, df))
```